# SQL Server : pivot functionality, need to pivot a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, pivot, correlated-subquery

I have data in SQL Server in the format below.

```
-ID          ID2  status  time
-1384904453  417  stop    2013-11-19 23:40:43.000
-1384900211  417  start   2013-11-19 22:30:06.000
-1384822614  417  stop    2013-11-19 00:56:36.000
-1384813810  417  start   2013-11-18 22:30:06.000
-1384561199  417  stop    2013-11-16 00:19:45.000
-1384554623  417  start   2013-11-15 22:30:06.000
-1384475231  417  stop    2013-11-15 00:26:58.000
-1384468224  417  start   2013-11-14 22:30:06.000
-1384388181  417  stop    2013-11-14 00:16:20.000
-1384381807  417  start   2013-11-13 22:30:06.000
-1384300222  417  stop    2013-11-12 23:50:11.000
-1384295414  417  start   2013-11-12 22:30:06.000
-1384218209  417  stop    2013-11-12 01:03:17.000
-1384209015  417  start   2013-11-11 22:30:06.000
```

What I need is to be able to show data in the following format.

```
-ID2  start                      stop
-417  2013-11-19 22:30:06.000    2013-11-19 23:40:43.000
-417  2013-11-18 22:30:06.000    2013-11-19 00:56:36.000
```

Is it possible to do this? I tried pivot in SQL Server but it only returns one record. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result, I would just apply the `row_number()` windowing function to the data so you can return multiple rows for each `ID2`:

```
select id2, start, stop
from
(
  select id2, status, time,
    row_number() over(partition by status
                      order by time) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(time)
  for status in (start, stop)
) piv
order by start desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f54c1/1).

You could also use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the final result:

```
select
  id2,
  max(case when status = 'start' then time end) start,
  max(case when status = 'start' then time end) stop
from 
(
  select id2, status, time,
    row_number() over(partition by status
                      order by time) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by id2, seq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f54c1/4)

Comment: I am really very thankful for this solution. without row_number() function I was getting only first record. and now I have learned a new function row_number(). thanks very much indeed :)

Answer (score 7):

You do not need a PIVOT query to get the information you are needing.  You can perform the following:

```
SELECT mt1.ID2, mt1.time AS start,
(
   SELECT TOP 1 mt2.time
   FROM MyTable AS mt2
   WHERE mt2.status = 'stop' 
     AND mt2.time >= mt1.time
   ORDER BY mt2.time 
) AS stop
FROM MyTable AS mt1
WHERE mt1.status = 'start'
```

If you are performing the above query in SQL Server and not MS Access then you will need to use `TOP(1)` instead of just `TOP 1`.

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25bb2/1/0) demonstrating the above query in SQL Server.